# Angular form reset after submit

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have Angular form (not reactive):

```
<form #form="ngForm" (submit)="submit(); form.reset()">
 <input ... />
</form>
```

But form does not reseting after submit, and inputs still marked as touched.

Please, explain, how can i reset form in Angular 5?

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/reset-form-demo-jdsdwe2

What i want: Clear focus and mark as untouched after submit.

Comment: Can you show this behavior on stackblitz? I ask it because it works for me

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]

Comment: @yurzui i add link in question

Comment: The field is cleared if I remove `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` and give a name to the input element. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reset-form-demo-jdsdwe2-nkwqxt).

Comment: @ConnorsFan ye, its work. You are right as always. Thanks )

Comment: You are welcome. I wish I were always right... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `@angular/forms` when you use a `<form>` tag it automatically creates a FormGroup.

For every contained ngModel tagged  it will create a FormControl and add it into the FormGroup created above; this FormControl will be named into the FormGroup using attribute name.

Example:

```
<form #f="ngForm">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="firstFieldVariable" name="firstField">
    <span>{{ f.controls['firstField']?.value }}</span>
</form>
```

When you mark it as **`standalone: true`** this will not happen (it will not be added to the FormGroup).